# How to read text files on nook?

Tags: nook

I can read text files directly on my Amazon Kindle, but apparently not 
on my Barnes/Noble Nook.

Is there some setting/etc I can tweak to read text files on the Nook?

Or do I just need to convert them to EPUB/PDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the [FAQs](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/u/Support-NOOK-Tablet/379003185) plain text files are compatible with some Nooks such as the Nook Tablet and Nook Color. On others such as the Nook Simple Touch you will need to convert the text file to an ePub file first using a tool like [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/).

Comment: I should have specified that I'm using the Nook Simple Touch Glowlight, and it appears you are correct: text files are not supported. Disappointing.